# why do we need SvcUtil.exe to create /generate proxy class

Tags: c#, wcf

Greetings!!

I am new to wcf and have some doubts.
I am able to create one wcf service and also able to consume that service  in a client application using "add service reference".. now my question is why do we need SvcUtil.exe to create /generate proxy class and then consumed by client, the same thing can be done using 'Add ref' easily. What is the exact purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't - I'm fairly sure they're equivalent. Obviously svcutil can be run from the command line whereas 'Add Web Reference' only works in Visual Studio but they do roughly the same thing.

We use svcutil not add web reference because the huge raft of files it creates became a version control nightmare.